# SQL Query that Blocks itself in Adventure Works

Tags: sql-server, blocking

I know it can be common for a query to block itself, especially if the query is from a report or SSIS package. What I am trying to do is create such a query against the adventureworks database for testing purposes. Have a script that auto-kills any process that is blocking for over 5 minutes but want to exclude those that are blocking them self and just haven't been able to figure one out to test against.